# shortest path alignment python

Tags: python, matrix

I have this function to find the shortest path in a matrix from M[0][0] to 
M[m][n]
I created the matrix and everything
I want to draw the shortest path everything in working yet aseq1, and aseq2 are empty
I'm unable to locate the problem

```
def path(seq1,seq2,matrix,gap):
    aseq1 = '' 
    aseq2 = ''

#reconstruction de l'alignement aseq1 pour la premiere sequence et aseq2 pour la deuxieme  
i = len(seq1[0])-1
j = len(seq2[1])-1
while i>0 and j>0:


    if i%10==0:
        stderr.write('.') 


 #utilisation de la matrice remplie pour tracer le chemin le plus court de M[0][0] a M[m][n]      
    score = M[i][j] 
    score_diag = M[i-1][j-1] 
    score_up = M[i][j-1] 
    score_left = M[i-1][j]

    if score == score_diag + d[[seq1[i-1]][seq2[j-1]]]:
        aseq1 = seq1[i-1] + aseq1 
        aseq2 = seq2[j-1] + aseq2 
        i -= 1 
        j -= 1
    if score == score_left + gap:
        aseq1 = seq1[i-1] + aseq1 
        aseq2 = '-' + aseq2 
        i -= 1 
    elif score == score_up + gap:
        aseq1 = '-' + aseq1 
        aseq2 = seq2[j-1] + aseq2 
        j -= 1
    else:
            print("Erreur?")


while i>0:
    # si j==0 avant i==0 on continue l'iteration avec i
    aseq1 = seq1[i] + aseq1 
    aseq2 = '-' + aseq2 
    i -= 1


while j>0: 
    # si i==0 avant j==o on continue l'iteration avec j
    aseq1 = '-' + aseq1 
    aseq2 = seq2[j] + aseq2
    print (aseq1,aseq2)
    j -= 1
print(aseq1,aseq2)
return (aseq1,aseq2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to indentation in Python. All of the code inside the first `while` loop is inside `if i%10==0`. If `i` is ever not divisible by 10, the program will loop forever.

This is what I'm talking about. Compare the tabbing to your code above:

```
while i>0 and j>0:
    if i%10==0:
        stderr.write('.') 

    #by performing a traceback of how the matrix was filled out above, 
    #i.e. we find a shortest path from a[n,m] to a[0,0] 
    score = M[i][j] 
    score_diag = M[i-1][j-1] 
    score_up = M[i][j-1] 
    score_left = M[i-1][j]
```

Comment: Look at your tabbing. `score = M[i][j]` is tabbed over twice, which puts it inside the scope of the `if` statement. You clearly only want it inside the scope of the `while` statement, so you only need it tabbed over once.

Comment: Probably because arrays are indexed starting at 0. If it has a length of 5, you can only index from 0 to 4, but you're indexing at 5 (you assign len to both i and j). @MunaAr

Comment: @MilieSmith  i edited the script and now everything iis functioning yet the aseq1, and seq2 are empty i ont know why

Comment: Try printing out seq1 and seq2 and see what values are in there. Trace the problem back to where it started. Find the *first* point in the program where things are not working as you would expect. The way to do that is to test the step right before the one that isn't working to see if *that's* giving you something you'd expect. If it is, you find out what went wrong. If it's not, you continue walking up the ladder.